# Ionic 2 app works using "ionic run android", but not on IonicView

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

When I run my Ionic2 app using ionic run android it works perfectly, and it also works using ionic serve, but when I'm trying to run it using ionic view all I see is a blank screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure that you only use cordova plugins that are supported by Ionic View? Otherwise you need to handle those separately.

Comment: I assume it might be it, but where can I see which plugins I'm using? In config.xml all I can see is the following plugins, which seems to be supported in IonicView:   
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.5"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1"/>

Comment: Well, all I've got is Camera, Console, Device, Facebook Connect, Slpashscreen, StatusBar, Whitelist and Keyboard. Most of them came with Ionic... which are not supported and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow below steps.

```
> ionic upload
```

Then go to your `Ionic view` app.

After that Tap `Sync to latest`.

Then `View app`.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed a few issues with what I presume is caching related while using Ionic View as new versions are not always uploaded or are uploaded incompletely .

- **Open the `ionic.config.json`and remove the value under app_id so its like so**

  ```
  {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "app_id": "",
    "v2": true,
    "typescript": true
  }
  ```
- **After this delete the app in Ionic View and rerun `ionic upload`.**

This should resolve a number of Ionic View upload bugs.

**Edit**

Also make sure to check the size of the uploaded app in Ionic View as it also commonly shows `NaN` value, this obviously indicating an upload error.

**Also worth noting is Ionic 2 is only supported from Android 4.4 and backward support to 4.1 can be achieved with Crosswalk Browser** [Ionic Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/overview/#browser-support)